How to create a pattern (regex) to group (up to) 5 letters/digits
I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to create a pattern (regex) to create groups of (up to) 5 letters/digits. Only letters (a-zA-Z) and digits (0-9) can be grouped, while spaces or other characters must be ignored.
As an example, a text with the following should create these groups:
The       book     is on the     table and 12 is     a number     


group 1: "Thebo"
group 2: "okiso"
group 3: "nthet"
group 4: "ablea"
group 5: "nd12i"
group 6: "sanum"
group 7: "ber"

Is it possible to create a regex for this purpose?

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

You would have to "ignore" characters that get matched, in the count that any quantifiers apply to - I don't see how that could be possible. (Unless you wanted to "list" every possible combination.) What is the context of this, where/how do you intend to apply this expression? Can't you replace any unwanted characters in a first step, which would make the desired grouping in a second step much more easy then?

You cannot skip parts of text inside a single match value. So, 1)  remove all non-letter/digits and then 2) get the chunks of 1-5 chars.

What is the context here? What programming language/application/platform are you using to apply the regex?

Is there a reason you have to do it with Regex?

It would seem best to remove characters to be skipped and then divide what is left into groups, but you could instead match the regular expression (?:[^a-zA-z\d]*[a-zA-z\d]){5}(?!$)|(?:[^a-zA-z\d]*[a-zA-z\d]){1,}(?=$). If the string were 'The.......book.....is.on.the.....table.and.12.is.....a number', this regex would match 'The.......bo', 'ok.....is.o', 'n.the.....t', 'able.a', 'nd.12.i', 's.....a num' and 'ber'. You would then have to remove the unwanted characters from each match. Demo...

...I have used periods rather spaces as the unwanted characters to make the example easier to follow.

I solved this issue using the CLOJURE language, but it was not possible (to me) create a single regex that would solve the problem without the help of logic using a programming language, that is, it was not possible to do so with just regex.
My question was whether I lacked sufficient knowledge in regex, or whether this type of issue really needed to be resolved the way I did (using a programming language).
Thank you to everyone who responded.
I consider my question resolved.

This probably shouldn't be an Answer.  IMO, it would make a better comment to add to your question.

TEST STRING:
--1-abcd--2ABCD34--

REGULAR EXPRESSION (1):
(?:[^a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z\d]){1,5}

 - Match 1: --1-abcd
 - Match 2: --2ABCD
 - Match 3: 34--

You would then have to remove the unwanted characters from each match.
REGULAR EXPRESSION (2):
[^a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d])[^a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d]?)[^a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d]?)[^a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d]?)[^a-zA-Z\d]*([a-zA-Z\d]?)

 - Match 1: --1-abcd
   - Group 1: 1
   - Group 2: a
   - Group 3: b
   - Group 4: c
   - Group 5: d

 - Match 2: --2ABCD
   - Group 1: 2
   - Group 2: A
   - Group 3: B
   - Group 4: C
   - Group 5: D

 - Match 3: 34--
   - Group 1: 3
   - Group 2: 4
   - Group 3: empty string
   - Group 4: empty string
   - Group 5: empty string

You would then have to remove the unwanted characters from each match or concatenate the capturing groups from each match.
